# Uint8Array values above 0x99 are printed as 0

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to read a binary file and pull out parts of it to print in hexadecimal. I have to read a file from the host (using `FileReader`'s `readAsArrayBuffer`). I noticed that something kept printing 0, and I can't figure out why.

Here's a minimal way to reproduce it:

```js
let t = new Uint8Array([ 0x26, 0xa6, 0x01, 0x99 ]);
console.log("T: " + t.map(b => b.toString(16)).join(" "));
```

Output:

```
T: 26 0 1 99
```

It seems like any value over `0x99` just gets printed as 0. If I initialize it with an array, like
`let t = [ 0x26, 0xa6, 0x01, 0x99 ];`
then it works.

It also works if I call Array.from() on the Uint8Array before calling "map" on it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is an excellent question about a non-obvious behavior of `map` on typed arrays. It has all of the information it needs, basically no extra information, a clear example... Nice one!

Comment: FWIW, I cover this "gotcha" in Chapter 11 of my new book out in June/July; see my profile for details if you're interested.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder nice, I'll check it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` on a typed array creates the same kind of typed array. Since you're returning strings from your callback, they get converted to integers that will fit in the type of the element of the array, or 0 if they can't be converted. The string `"a6"` (for instance) can't be converted implicitly, so you get `0` instead.

Use the mapping facility of [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) instead to create an array of strings from the callback that you can `join` together:

```js
let t = new Uint8Array([ 0x26, 0xa6, 0x01, 0x99 ]);
console.log("T: " + Array.from(t, b => b.toString(16)).join(" "));
```

---

It's worth noting that the `26` you're getting in the output from your original code is misleading. :-) That's the *decimal* value 26 (whereas `0x26` is `38` in decimal). You're passing in `0x26`, which gets converted to `"26"`, which gets converted to `26` (decimal, not hex), then converted back to `"26"` by the `join` function.

Comment: To complement your answer, also `0x26` is in fact `38` in decimal. Therefore, even the "good string" has a huge potential to be a wrong value in the end.

Comment: @ClaudioBusatto - Right, exactly, that's what I was trying to point out but didn't quite manage to. Doh! :-)